# WAR file build in tomcat project

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, ant, war, tomcat8

I have a traditional tomcat project configured in eclipse. I could run it successfully through eclipse by providing the tomcat configuration like below,

**Window->Preferences->Tomcat**
Provided the Tomcat home and configuration file tomcat server.xml file.

In server.xml file i have provided the context declaration details to access the application.

Now, i would like to build the WAR file for this project using eclipse or ANT. When i try to export the WAR file using eclipse, the module name for the project is not captured.

Could anyone please give me the suggestion to build the tomcat deployable WAR file for **Eclipse->Tomcat project**.

Thanks in advance..,

Comment: bit not clear with tomcat project ? you have WAR file and want to deploy into tomcat right ?

Comment: I cannot export the WAR file using eclipse because it's traditional tomcat project. I have configured the tomcat plugin into eclipse to start the project through tomcat. In eclipse you can see the Tomcat project option like dynamic web application project. I'm looking for the option to build the war file using eclipse export or ANT build option.